# Dealing with sizeof() array inside of array

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, sizeof

My question for today is how to deal with complex structures with sizeof().
I have a structure like this

`std::map<Int32, std::unordered_set<std::pair<DescID, Int32>>> objActions;`

The problem is i don't know how to find actual size of this variable. If there would be just a map i could just multiply its size by sizeof, but in this particular case i am not really sure what i should multiply with. Is it should be something like

`(sizeof(unordered_set<..., ...>) * map.at_some_iterator.size()) + sizeof(map)`?

Thanks.

Comment: `sizeof` of an object tells the size of the object itself, not whatever data that it might have pointers to. Therefore the `sizeof` operator of e.g. `std::unordered_set` doesn't tell how many elements as in the set. Why do you need to use `sizeof`? What is the actual and real problem you need to solve? Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need to write it to a file. API that im using allows to do it with function that takes pointer to data and its size.

Comment: _"If there would be just a map i could just multiply its size by sizeof"_ -- No, this would not tell you the size of the map. It would tell you the size of `size()` maps, which isn't at all the same thing. `sizeof()` does not know or care about any dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: You can calculate the size of each unordered_set using `(sizeof(DescID) + sizeof(Int32)) * set.size()`. Because each set can be a different size you can't just multiply that by the number of items in the map; you'd need to iterate the map and add them up.

Comment: @Danchyg1337 You can't serialize a map like that. The contents of the map are not actually stored within the map object itself, they are stored in many separate allocations that form a tree. Writing/reading the raw memory of the map object is just going to preserve a pointer that won't be valid anymore when restored. You need to iterate the whole map yourself and write it out in some serialization format.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks! But how to calculate the whole map then?

Comment: @cdhowie Hm. Which format would you suggest?

Comment: @Danchyg1337 That depends on many factors. Have a look at JSON, XML, Protocol Buffers, etc. Pick the one that seems best suited for your use-case.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks. I would probably choose JSON.

Comment: There are many existing serialization libraries and frameworks for C++. I really recommend you try to use one of them instead of "reinventing the wheel". Good serialization is far from trivial, it's error-prone and takes time to get it right. The existing libraries have spend many years to get it to work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No doubt. I know few, but for my current work im allowed to use either std or API im working with, no 3rd party frameworks :(
At least i have built-in functions to work with json, so i can try to use it instead. Thanks again for reply.

Comment: sizeof not returns size of array, size of array in bytes.

Comment: @GobeRadJem32 That is the point! To get size in bytes :)

Comment: @Danchyg1337 The size in bytes will be of no help to you at all. If you want to write your map to a file, you have to loop though it and write each element individually. Then to write your unordered_sets you have to loop through and write each element individually. There are no shortcuts (apart from using a serialization library but you've already rejected that).

Comment: @john Thanks, i was afraid that there is no easy way.